# Elasticsearch: check exist a key in the field of type object

Tags: elasticsearch

My index `test` has the next mapping:

```
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "bar" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "baz" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "foo" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "enabled" : false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The index has 2 documents:

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "max_score": 1.0,
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "test",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "1",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
        "baz": 123,
        "bar": [
          "php",
          "python"
        ],
        "foo": {
          "1": "bla",
          "2": "blu"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "test",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "2",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
        "baz": 123,
        "bar": [
          "java",
          "python"
        ],
        "foo": {
          "3": "blue",
          "4": "blae"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get only the docs that contain key 1 in the field `foo`. (So in my case this is a document where _id = 1).

Which query is suitable for this?

Elasticsearch version 6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set `"enabled": false` in your mapping. Set it to `true` or rather remove it which would again set it to `true` by default.

The purpose of [`enabled`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) if it is set to `true` is that it would allow ES to create an inverted index for the fields so that they would be searchable. Making it `false` would mean that ES would simply skip reading those fields and its contents entirely.

Note that by default if you do not specify it in your mapping, it is set to `true`.

Below is how your mapping would be:

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
          "bar" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "baz" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "foo" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "enabled" : true       <---- Note this, either this or remove this to have this option
          }

      }
    }
}
```

Once you do that, you can just make use of exists query to get what you want.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "foo.1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Suggested Solution:

From what I understand based on the comments, you have `ids` of documents as `sub-fields` inside your `object` type.

Why not change your mapping to something like below:

```
POST my_sample_index
{
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "bar":{
            "type":"keyword"
         },
         "baz":{
            "type":"long"
         },
         "foo":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "id":{                       <--- Field for id
                  "type":"keyword"
               },
               "value":{                    <--- Corresponding field for its value
                  "type":"text"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

That way the document would be as below:

```
POST my_sample_index/_doc/1
{
   "baz":123,
   "bar":[
      "java",
      "python"
   ],
   "foo":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "value":"blue"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "value":"black"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now you can simply query based on the value of `id` field with as simple as [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

```
POST my_exists_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "foo.id": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can see that number of fields in your mapping would only be two `id` and `value` instead of having it created dynamically esp when the number of documents you'd possibly have would be non-deterministic.

**Important Note:** You may also want to check [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype instead of `object`. Also if you are using `nested` datatype, you have to make use of [`Nested Queries`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).  Please do read the aforementioned links as why I'm suggesting you to go through them.

Hope it helps!

Comment: the problem is that if the field `foo` has many unique keys (in my case, it is ids of docs), it will begin to increase the mappings. so that's why I've decided to set `"enabled" : false`

Comment: @lemon yup yup, its tricky I know, but I've provided another solution under `Suggested Solution` section, could you please check and let me know if you have any queries or concerns about it.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer! But the idea of using documents ids as sub-fields inside object type  was implemented so that with large search requests it would be possible to display only the necessary sub-field in the source field (for example, `"_source": "foo.1"`)

Comment: @lemon, sure, I mean so that's why I've mentioned in the comment to try and see if you could use `nested` fields/query. Check them out and you can get what you want from its `inner_hits` feature I suppose. Agree it may not be the best and still return the entire document, but inner_hits would help you which `sub-field` or rather `nested document` alone the query hit. I think that would help you for this use-case.

Comment: @lemon On an additional note, Are you using any application layer? I mean you can further parse required JSON response in your application layer, of course you would need to add more code over there :( but important thing is your data-model is maintainable and also remains consistent :)

Comment: regarding `nested` type, it also increases  the mappings, like the `object` type with `"enabled" : true` :(

Comment: Increase mappings?!! you just have to replace `"type": "object"`  with `"type": "nested"`. Note that I'm talking w.r.t the solution I've mentioned instead of dynamic mapping that you are currently using.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault. I've set `enabled: true` with `nested` type instead `enabled: false`. Thank you again!